# How to keep Telegram bot running in production with Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment, telegram-bot

I apologies if my question is bit abstract. I have a telegram bot that is running inside Telegram, and a rails application that receives all the data submitted from the bot into a web view. Now I want to deploy the application in Production, but I have no idea on how to keep the bot running everytime I perform an action on the bot.
Any ideas or suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Heroku as a deployment solution,
You will need to upgrade from the default free dynos to at least the hobby dynos.

Free dynos go to sleep after 30 minuts of inactivity, so if you want to keep the bot working all the time, you will need to upgrade.

See more details about the plans here:
https://www.heroku.com/pricing

Comment: Actually, I am using Capistrano and would like to know if a script like solution will work, such as calling the script everytime the but works.